# Can Azure Application Insights reaching daily cap cause my app service to return a 503?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

So I have a QA environment hosted on a service app, and the site seems to load perfectly fine.  But I've been noticing that occasionally when the application insights daily data cap is hit, it will start returning 503 errors from the app service.  I find it hard to believe that it would be caused by this, but it seems to be the cause of it.  If that's what does happen, is there a way to turn off App insights so it doesn't take down the site when the cap is hit?

Comment: This is definitely not expected. If Application Insights resource reaches daily cap then it returns specific response code (4xx) and SDK will just drop the data. The latter should result in less pressure on resources and should not cause 503. Do you have an environment where it is strongly correlated? If you have support plan - do you think you can open a support case?

Answer (score 1):

No, just because the `daily cap` of Application Insights is reached, the App service will not return failure code 503. It will only display a warning text message in the Azure portal, your App service will continue to serve requests just like as before.